# Converting Between Incompatible Types

Tags: c++, casting

In some places in my code, I use the `_mm_prefetch` function, which takes in a `const char *` and `int`. The first parameter being the memory address of the object to prefetch. Since it's a `const char *` instead of `void*`, it needs to be cast.

Note: in the below context `nextActive` is a pointer to object.

Originally, I had:

```
_mm_prefetch( (const char *)this->nextActive, _MM_HINT_T1 );
```

This works fine; however, this leads to a warning, regarding [C++ Core Guidelines Pro.safety: Type-safety profile Type.4.](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#SS-type)

I could use `reinterpret_cast`, but, that results in a warning violating Type 1a of the above (*Don't use `reinterpret_cast`*)

Then, I thought, well, I can cast to `void*` then to `const char*`, but that results in a warning of Type 1d (*Don't cast between pointer types when the conversion could be implicit*)

```
_mm_prefetch( static_cast<const char *>( static_cast<void *>( this->nextActive ) ), _MM_HINT_T1 );
```

Short of just suppressing the warnings when using `_mm_prefetch`, is there a proper way to covert between two incompatible types? Or are there always going to be warnings, because (of course) you probably shouldn't be casting between different types?

Comment: It's weird you get a warning.  `(const char *)this->nextActive` is perfectly safe.  In fact, you have to do something like that if you want to read/write from/to binary files.

Comment: @NathanOliver: It's not weird; the core C++ guidelines don't like reinterpret casts, regardless of how you spell them or how "safe" they might be in some cases.

Comment: @ChrisMM: If you're doing prefetching of bytes of memory, why do you care what the core guidelines say? You're deep in the bowels of very low-level C++ code, optimizing things to squeeze out all the performance you can. That's not a part of your codebase that the core guidelines are meant to apply to.

Comment: @NicolBolas, essentially, I'm trying to eliminate all warnings (include from Code Analysis), since that's our company's policy. There is exceptions where it can be suppressed in specific cases, which I'm thinking this might be one.

Comment: @NathanOliver, should have specified, the warnings are from VS Code Analysis, not the standard W3/W4 warnings.

Comment: I wonder if something like this might work? `void* ptr = this->nextActive; _mm_prefetch(static_cast<const char*>(ptr), _MM_HINT_T1);`. The only cast is from `void*` to `const char*` which should be allowed.

Comment: @Kevin, just tried it, that gets around the warnings.

Comment: @ChrisMM I made it an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
void* ptr = this->nextActive;
_mm_prefetch(static_cast<const char*>(ptr), _MM_HINT_T1);
```

The only cast is from `void*` to `const char*` which is allowed.

Comment: Gets around the warning; though, in this case, might just be better to suppress the warning, instead of introducing the temporary variable.

Comment: @ChrisMM The compiler can almost definitely optimize out the temporary variable and the cast. If you use this in a number of places you can put it in a function (that can be inlined).

Comment: I meant for readability; not concerned about one variable.

Comment: @ChrisMM Not sure if it helps readability but: `static_cast<const char*>(static_cast<void*>(this->nextActive))`

Comment: @TedLyngmo, that results in a CA warning

Comment: @ChrisMM I see. Odd though. Seems like the same thing.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, the Type 1d warning is for not casting when implicit is fine, which `static_cast<void*>(this->nextActive)` could be done implicitly instead.

Comment: @ChrisMM Silly me, I now see that you tried that already. :)