# Cpp Core Guidelines: "const char *" to "const uint8_t *" without reinterpret_cast and C-style cast?

Tags: c++, c++17, cpp-core-guidelines

For code like this:

```
#include <cstdint>

extern const char *f();
extern void g(const uint8_t *);

int main()
{
    const char *p = f();
    g(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t *>(p));
}
```

`clang-tidy -checks='cppcoreguidelines-*'` generates warning:

```
do not use reinterpret_cast [cppcoreguidelines-pro-type-reinterpret-cast]
```

and indeed there is such paragraph in [CppCoreGuidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#prosafety-type-safety-profile).

But how it is possible to avoid `reinterpret_cast` or C-style cast for case like `const char *` -> `const uint8_t *`?

Is this bug in CppCoreGuidelines ?

Comment: `g( static_cast<const uint8_t*>( static_cast<const void*>( p ) ) );` ?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66280204/converting-between-incompatible-types) for a similar question

Comment: Casting via void should also give a warning as it is similarily unsafe.

Comment: Problem is that `char` can be signed and thus simply casting is not possible.
If you can afford copying memory a simple workaround would also be to `std::memcpy(f_ui8, f, size);`

Comment: @André Cast to "const void *" don't give similar warning. Why it should? Casting pointer to pointer looks more safe then using "big gun" as reinterpret_cast that can cast anything to anytihng if they has the same size.

Comment: I never said it would warn, I just feel it should. You are reinterpreting content, so the cast should be clean. Just tested: Indeed no compiler warning, just my static code analyzer complaining. So +1 for @ChrisMM's solution as it solves your problem.

Comment: @user1244932 The reason this doesn't give a warning is purely because you have tricked the static analyser. It's a false negative. As André's second comment explains *this cast is not generally safe*. Using `std::memcpy` is the only "save"way to go in general. You can make your way safe by (statically) checking that `char` is an unsigned type on your platform (… which it probably *isn't*).

Comment: Since c++17, signed and unsigned can be assigned (reinterpreted) back and forth w/o issue so long as they are the same size. This is because signed types are now required to be two's compliment.